# VScode extension Markdown All in One toggle list

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

With Visual Studio Code extension [Markdown All in One - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one), I can toggle list with command `markdown.extension.editing.toggleList` when editing a markdown document.

It will cycle through `- -> * -> + -> 1. -> 1)`

But I want to use two of them: `*`, `1.`

Is there any configuration for it? A short cyclic list will save time to trigger the command more times.

Comment: you can create an issue at the extension repo or even create a pull request

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, rioV8.  I created a pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pull request [Let Toggle List cycle through a configurable list of markers](https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/pull/1145) was merged, and the configuration will be available soon in the next build.

```js
"markdown.extension.list.toggle.candidate-markers": [
   "*",
   "1.",
]
```